# Word/phrase that can be used to say that a particular word doesn't describe something

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

> John says he's swimming, when he is treading water.

By definition, *swimming* involves voluntary movement of the body.

What word or phrase can we use to tell John that he can't be swimming because he's not moving himself?

Comment: `Swimming` is inapt/inapplicable/ill-suited/unfitting here.

Comment: Just a technicality... are you saying you are able to thread water without (voluntarily) moving your body? I _think_ even the last person reportedly able to do that was _walking_.

Answer (score 6):

***[misnomer](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/misnomer)***

> a misapplied or inappropriate name or designation.

thefreedictionary.com

***"to call this swimming would be a misnomer."***

Answer (score 1):

***Strictly speaking***, @Okoning is quite correct in saying John's usage is a "misnomer". I will admit my first thought was a misnomer always and only means *an instance of the use of a wrong **name***, but I see OED say it can also be used of *a misapplication of a term* (such as the verb "swimming").

In practice though, I think in normal conversation you'd be more likely to say...

> Strictly speaking, John, you're not really "swimming", because you're not moving *through* the water. You're just *treading water in one spot*.
>
> [***strictly speaking***](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/strictly-speaking) - being completely accurate <sub><sup>(Cambridge Dictionaries Online)</sup></sub>